# Generate getters and setters in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, keyboard-shortcuts, getter-setter

I Need to know how to have NetBeans generate getters and setters using a shortcut.

Comment: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/editor-codereference.html#generatecode

Comment: i dont want to use google, i am here to ask and you should not read my questions in future. Bye Sharma

Comment: possible duplicate of [NetBeans Tips and Tricks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628830/netbeans-tips-and-tricks)

Comment: @Zvjezdan Have a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users, Saurabh isn't the only one that would rather you google for it first.

Comment: @DennisMeng I googled it, and guess what I found? This.

Comment: @WilliamOliver Good, you're searching.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Position the cursor inside the class, then press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Ins</kbd> and select `Getters and Setters` from the contextual menu.

Comment: For MAC users it's ctr + i https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/mac.html

Comment: doesn't work (setters )with SimpleStringProperty, tested on netbeans 8.1

Comment: In my case (Netbeans 8.2, Eclipse keymap config) it's CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+e ("Encapsulate Fields)

Comment: For me as well in 8.2 Alt + e did not worked .CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+e worked fine   Thanks @AydinK.

Comment: Menu version: (position cursor in class) `Source > Insert Code... > Getter and Setter...`