# How to access a value of a private instance variable from a different class?

Tags: java, user-interface

I am creating a simple GUI game (number guessing) in Java.

Apparently, I have a button called `Give Up`.

When I click the `Give Up` button, I want to display the answer on a textarea.

However, the `targetNumber` variable is declared as private:

```
public class GameUtility {
    private String targetNumber = "2543";

    //rest of the code
}

class GiveUpButton implements ActionListener { //Inner class
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent gEvent) {

        GameUtility utility = new GameUtility();
        textArea.append(utility.targetNumber); //How to access the value of targetNumber?
    }
}
```

How can I access a value of a private variable?

Comment: A private member or method is accessible only within its own class.You need accessors. The principle behind it is called encapsulation.

Comment: When you do not want to create a getter/setter method, you may be interested in using [reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196192/how-do-i-read-a-private-field-in-java). Be aware that this is a dirty hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the state of the managed bean `accessible`, you need to add `setter` and `getter` methods for that state.

Once the setter and getter (accessor) methods have been added, you can update and access the value of the `private` instance. The code should look like the following example:

```
public class AccessorExample {
    private String attribute;

    public String getAttribute() {
        return attribute;
    }

    public void setAttribute(String attribute) {
        this.attribute = attribute;
    }
}
```

Letting access the information inside the `private` instance from **outside of the class**, only if they ask through a provided mechanism we will call method. The mechanisms for asking an object to reveal information about itself we can call the `getter` method (e.g. `accessorExample.getAttribute();`).

Comment: Is it a good idea to combine the setter/getter methods into one?

Comment: If you need to update this private instance in time, you need to implement the setter method as well inside the same class. This is related to the encapsulation principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)).

Answer (score 2):

The `private` modifier implies that you don't have access to the property directly. But perhaps more importantly, `private` implies that you *shouldn't* have access to the property directly. Create a `getter` for providing access to external classes:

```
public class GameUtility {
    private String targetNumber = "2543";

    public String getTargetNumber() {
        return targetNumber;
    }

    //rest of the code
}

class GiveUpButton implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent gEvent) {
        GameUtility utility = new GameUtility();
        textArea.append(utility.getTargetNumber());
    }
}
```

---

See also: [Java Documentation on Access Control](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way is to create appropriate `Getters` and `Setters`.

[See this post to get more insights as how do getters and setters work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2036988/2815219)

```
public class AccessorExample {
    private String attribute;

    public String getAttribute() {
        return attribute;
    }

    public void setAttribute(String attribute) {
        this.attribute = attribute;
    }
}
```

Most of the IDEs provide support to directly generate `getters` and `setters`.

1. [Generate Getters and setters in Netbeans.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21074418/2815219)
2. [Generate Getters and setters in Eclipse.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7221702/2815219)